# BigQuery Command Tool - Script

Tags: google-bigquery, spritebatch

I could get data loaded using Big Query Command tool. I can load the data using individual commands but when I put it in Bat script it is not working.

Have anyone tried it ? Doe Unix scripting works?

Comment: What is the error you see and the contents of the script? Scripting BQ jobs works.

Comment: Hi Mario: first problem is when I am running the script it opens explorer to accept the terms. can it be silent / default? and secondly, after doing that it asks it exits the script saying  "You are now logged in as [XXYYZZ@gmail.com].
Your current project is [AABBCC].  You can change this setting by r
unning:
  $ gcloud config set project <project>" Then script exits

Comment: Are you meaning when running the bq command? Could you upload a screenshot of that?

Comment: Here is script 

gcloud auth login
bq shell --project_id=plenary-network-691
load data.Location_Summary gs://virginpocbucket/input_test1.txt  ID:String,name:string
sleep 100

screenshot attached

Comment: you're calling the shell option which opens an interactive shell, which obviously it's not the way you want to run your request. It could be something like bq query options YOUR_QUERY or in your case "bq --project_id=plenary-network-691 load data.Location_Summary gs://virginpocbucket/input_test1.txt ID:String,name:string". I don't see the screenshot.